# Check if npm dependencies from pacakge.json are installed without network

Tags: npm, npm-install

How can I have npm tell me if all dependencies are already installed without checking the network?

My goal is to first test locally if anything needs to be installed, and then only if something is missing, I'll run a normal `npm install` to install it.  I'm trying to avoid the initial check across the network though if everything is already there.

This is also given a package.json file with fixed versions, since obviously allowing auto upgraded packages would always require a remote repository check.

**Update:**
I've tested `npm list` which doesn't seem to access the network, and it prints out "UNMET DEPENDENCY" if something is in package.json but not installed.  Is that the best way to accomplish this?

I'll probably end up with something like:
`npm list | grep -c 'UNMET DEPENDENCY'`

Comment: My update does seem to work, but I think the answer from @apfrancis is a better fit.  Marking as correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything that will explicitly tell you whether dependencies were installed from a remote repo or not. However I think that the [shrinkpack](https://github.com/JamieMason/shrinkpack) package will help you achieve your aim.

Shrinkpack will cache your npm modules locally and only contact a remote repository when existing modules change or new modules are added.

I've used this in the past to reduce the number of network requests required for an `npm install`.

Comment: Running `npm install --loglevel http` will show you when it hits the network during installation as well.